# C# WPF ListView как изменить значение ячейки?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Есть класс Product

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Placement { get; set; }
    public int NumPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Есть коллекция:

```
List<Product> products;
```

Так же добавление элемента в коллекцию:

```
products.Add(new Product { Title = "Adobe Photoshop", Number = 1, NumPrice = 10, Price = 20, Placement = "в наличии" });
LW.Items.Refresh();
```

Как изменить определенное значение. Допустим я хочу число Number заменить с единицы на 2, а также Adobe Photoshop заменить на Adobe Dreamviewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша коллекция прикреплена к `ListView` через `ItemsSource`? Если да, то ваш класс `Product` должен имплементировать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, и значение подхватится само.

При этом `LW.Items.Refresh();` будет не нужно.

```
class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value,
                         [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;

        field = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { Set(ref title, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Находим нужный объект
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title == "Adobe Photoshop");
    // Если что-то нашлось
    if (product != null)
    {
        // Меняем свойства
        product.Title = "Adobe Dreamviewer";
        // И просим контрол обновить данные
        LV.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

---

Более правильный подход, который позволит вам проектировать бизнес-логику в отрыве от представления - реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` в вашем классе `Product`:

```
public class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Title)));
        }
    }

...
```

Контролы WPF поддерживают это и при получении события обновятся автоматически, без вызова `Items.Refresh()`

---

Обычно делают базовый класс и реализуют в нем `INotifyPropertyChanged` (примерно как в соседнем ответе). А все классы, которые будут выведены в GUI (VM-классы) наследуют от него, это позволяет повторно использовать код реализации `INPC`

Comment: А если к примеру у нас есть Number, где часто встречается единица. Как изменить Number = 1 именно у Adobe Photoshop?

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title == "Adobe Photoshop" && p.Number == 1)`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы гений! :)